# Store same fields twice during serialization

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I have a very simple POCO like:

```
public class Sample()
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to use a custom Attribute like [AdditionalLowerField] as below

```
public class Sample()
{
     public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     [AdditionalLowerField]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

so that in MongoDB LastName field is serialized twice, with an additional lowered case field like this:

```
{
    _id : ......,
    FirstName : "Mario",
    LastName : "Special Case",
    LastNameLower : "special case"
}
```

I'm trying to figure this out from doc http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#write-a-custom-attribute but it's not so complete and I don't find good examples for this scenario.

**Update**: I know that an additional read-only Property can be used together with a [BsonElement] attribute to store its value in MongoDB during serialization and avoid to get it back during deserialization like described in [opt-in paragraph](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#opt-in):

```
    [BsonElement]
    public string LastNameLower
    {
        get { return LastName.ToLowerInvariant(); }
    }
```

But I'd like to avoid creation of additional properties if possible.

Does anybody have experience on this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: You can do that by creating a new serializer. Is that what you want?

Comment: The problem with Serializer is that you can define how to serialize the value, but Name of the field is not available in Serialize method. Therefore I'm unable to save an additional field with Lower at the end like this:

    {
        var bsonWriter = context.Writer;
        bsonWriter.WriteString(field.Value);
        bsonWriter.WriteName(field.Name + "Lower");
        bsonWriter.WriteString(field.Value.ToLowerInvariant);                    }

Comment: Why would you need the name? You need to use reflection to find a property with your attribute, get's its value and ToLower it.